# Desktop application with NFC reader and Android phone - Exchanging files

Tags: nfc, nfc-p2p

I am trying to build a prototype - Windows based touch Kiosk application. This application am trying to NFC enable with ACR122U or SCl3711 . I am planning on interfacing an NFC enabled Android phone with this application.

Typical use cases would be

- User can pick a image in the kiosk and tap the phone on the NFC
  reader of the kiosk to get the image into the android app of the
  phone.
- User can return a image from the android app to the kiosk by
  tapping on the NFC reader of the kiosk.

with my limited research i learnt few things - Just want to know if am right on track

1. I would need a Windows Kiosk application( .NET or JAVA) that can
   work with ACR122U. Negotiating connection with LLCP and SNEP for
   send and receive NDEF messages. Can i send a image as a NDEF
   message. How to implement LLCP and SNEP protocols in .NET or JAVA
   for ACR122U are there any libraries / samples ?
2. I would need a android application that can use NFC to receive the
   image and store the image inside the App.
3. should i be using NDEF pushing or Android beaming for image transfer
   ?

I also got some advice on using Arduino board with a NFC shield and Android phone to implement the above prototype - is it possible to implement a file transfer with the NFC shield (seedstudio.com)?

Comment: I would use beam, it is designed for that purpose. But that would mean implementing beam on the kiosk, which may not be trivial! How large is your image?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - My images shouldn't be more than 100 KB. I could be wrong someone pointed me that we cannot implement beam on a non-android device (my kiosk is windows based) is it ture? Any insights on programming reader like ACR122U with LLCP/SNEP, libraries?

Comment: It may be true; it is an Android protocol, and even if you could reproduce it on another OS, you would have to implement it yourself..

Comment: I just looked into the following link where someone has exactly done what is required for me. https://code.google.com/p/java-android-beam-api/. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Sounds good! Someone already did it for you :)

Comment: Yeah it has the piece for PC to receive, guess i will have to figure the PC to send part. Will keep the forum posted. Thanks for your replies

Comment: To be precise library ismb-npp-java is the best match for my requirement to do this prototype in java